# android specified locale for the whole application

Tags: android

What i tried is as follows

```
final Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        final Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

i wants to set a particular locale to the whole application and i am doing it at Application class level, but above given lines seems to be not working as when i am changing the Locale language specification from the setting the Date-picker do not have an effect of the application class specified locale and taking the locale from setting language specification.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Is the problem that the app doesn't show texts from string.xml in the right language?

Comment: no i wants to set the en us as language for whole application  that even on changing the language from settings will not effect my application

Comment: I see! I do something very similar in one of my apps, using the same code as above. Only difference that I can spot is that I do it on Activity level rather than on Application level. I suggest that you move the code to one of your activities' onCreate/onResume methods just to see if that helps.

Comment: yes but i wants to do it for my whole application rather than a particular activity, is it possible?? because doing for each activity may increase code repeat unnecessarily. is there any way to do same at application class.

Comment: That I don't know. I have some other requirements in my application that makes it impossible for me to set it on an Application level. One idea is to use a custom super activity e.g. MyActivity extends Activity. Put your code in the onCreate method of MyActivity, and let all your activities extend MyActivity instead of Activity.

Comment: many thanks for the help, if i will not be able to achieve through Application class than i will try to use in the same way what you suggested!!

Comment: Is that something you can use? In that case I'll write it as a suggested answer to your question and clean up my comments here. Not supposed to answer questions in the comment field. :/

Comment: i understood yours suggestion completely!!

Comment: my mail id is upadhyay.jitesh@gmail.com please share yours as well!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it works setting a locale on Application level, since I haven't tried it myself.

A workaround (that I know works) is to create a super activity e.g. `MyActivity extends Activity`. Put the code

```
final Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
final Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

in the `onCreate()` method of MyActivity, and let all your activities extend MyActivity instead of Activity.